# Key Mapping for ViPlugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, vim, key-bindings

I want to duplicate some of my Vi key mappings in the ViPlugin for Eclipse. Specifically, I use "jj" for the Esc key, which is done like this in my rc file:

```
map! jj <Esc>
```

The ViPlugin User Manual explains how to set up some rc file type of configurations. The example given is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
    <shiftwidth>4</shiftwidth>
    <vimcursor>true</vimcursor>
    <ignorecase>true</ignorecase>
    <expandtab>true</expandtab>
    <hlsearch>true</hlsearch>
    <incsearch>true</incsearch>
    <undolevels>1000</undolevels>
    <wordseparators>.,(,), ,TAB,ENTER,:,;,?,+,=,ANGLE_BRACKET_RIGHT,ANGLE_BRACKET_LEFT,*,{,},",|,COMMA,-,\,/,@,[,],},~,!,#,$,%,^,',`,´,AND</wordseparators>
</xml>
```

The User Manual also mentions about a handful of Eclipse Actions that the ViPlugin implements, which can be assigned Keybinding (for example, EraseBackOneWord and AddOneLevelOfIndentation), but that doesn't seem to be helpful here.

Comment: Confused: why is this a bad question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you trying to achieve isn't possible using the **ViPlugin**. It supports a limited set of rebindable actions which are accessible through the default eclipse key bindings menu.